# Flink Kafka connector - commit offset without checkpointing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a question regarding Flink Kafka Consumer (FlinkKafkaConsumer09).
I've been using this version of connector:
flink-connector-kafka-0.9_2.11-1.1.2 (connector version is 0.9, akka version is 2.11, flink version is 1.1.2)

I gather communication data from kafka within 5-minutes tumbling windows. From what I've seen, the windows are aligned with system time (for example windows end in 12:45, 12:50, 12:55, 13:00 etc.)
After window is closed, its records are processed/aggregated and sent via Sink operator to database.

Simplified version of my program:

```
env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(topicName,jsonMapper, properties))
    .keyBy("srcIp", "dstIp", "dstPort")
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)))
    .apply(new CounterSum<>())
    .addSink(new DbSink(...));
```

However I need to commit offset in kafka. From what I've read, the only way in FlinkKafkaConsumer09 is to turn on checkpointing. I do it like this:

```
env.enableCheckpointing(300000); // 5 minutes
```

Checkpointing stores state of all operators. After checkpoint is complete, the offset is comitted to kafka.
My checkpoints are stored via FsStateBackend in taskmanager system file structures (the first problem - older checkpoint data are not deleted, I saw some bugs being reported for this).
The second problem is when the checkpoint is triggered. If triggered at the beginning of the window, resulting checkpoint file is small, on the other side when triggered just before window is closed, resulting state is large (for example 50MB), because there are already many communication records in this window. The checkpoint process usually takes less than 1-2s, however when the checkpoint is triggered after the window is closed and while processing aggregations and DB sinks, the checkpoint process takes 45s.

But the whole point is that I don't need state checkpointing at all. All I need is to commit offset to kafka after window is closed, is processed and resulting data are sinked to db (or at the beginning of another window). If failover occured, flink would fetch last offset from kafka and would read data from last 5-minute interval again. Because last failed result was not sent to db, there would be no duplicate data being sent to DB and rereading last 5 minute interval is no overhead.

So basically I have 2 questions:

1. Is there any way how to achieve checkpointing being turned off
   and only commit offsets like described above ?
2. If not, is there any way how to align checkpointing with start of
   the window ? I read flink documentation - there is feature called
   savepoints (i.e. manual checkpoints), but it is meant to be used
   from command line. I would need to call savepoint from code on
   window start - state would be small and checkpoint process would be
   quick.

Comment: I know this is almost 5 years old, but I actually have the same concern. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: You should post another question. The context may be different and Flink has evolved a lot since 5 years.